# How to Log a Python Crash in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

How can a log of the crash of a Python script running on Windows be generated? A python program mysteriously crashes every few hours and the application window is closed so there is not sign of the error messages from the crash.

On Linux we can do `python script.py >> /logdir/script.py.log 2>&1`. What about on Windows?

The script running is basically an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    if ...
        ...
    else:
        ....
```

Comment: suggest using logging statements so you don't need to capture program output

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: @JasonS Should I put my code (`while True` loop) into a `try... except Exception e` and do `logging.error(e)`?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
logger = logging.getLogger("myApplication")

while True:
  try:
    if ...
        ...
    else:
        ....
  except Exception:
    logger.exception("???")
```

and [setup logging to log to a file](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file)?

Then, even if there is an exception, the program can keep going. If it truly is a crash that can't be caught as an exception, you should put logging statements in your program so you can see what happened successfully before the crash.